# Flink 1.6 Python Streaming API Data Sources (Kafka Consumer)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to access to one or more Kafka topics with Python Streaming API in Flink 1.6

Has anyone done accessing to Kafka with Python ?

In the official Flink documentation, there are some examples but I could not see Kafka source.

Any help/advice on reading Kafka into python is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Streaming Data Sources Examples**

```
env  = factory.get_execution_environment()

\# read text file from local files system
localLiens = env.read_text("file:///path/to/my/textfile")

\# read text file from a HDFS running at nnHost:nnPort
hdfsLines = env.read_text("hdfs://nnHost:nnPort/path/to/my/textfile")

\# create a set from some given elements
values = env.from_elements("Foo", "bar", "foobar", "fubar")

\# generate a number sequence
numbers = env.generate_sequence(1, 10000000)
```

Comment: Your example code isn't really streaming. It's taking a static set of data, not sure why you're showing it

Comment: *The Python streaming layer, is actually a thin wrapper layer for the existing Java streaming APIs.*... So, did you try importing the Kafka related classes and using them?